# Wanting to use a UIViewController flow for two separate cases

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `UIViewControllers` - one that handles the camera, and the other that allows the taken picture/video to be edited. These two go hand-in-hand to form part of a picture-taking flow within my app. I want to use these two controllers in two different circumstances:

The first is that after the image has been edited, it's passed to another `UIViewController` to add some additional info to the image.

The second is that after the image has been edited, it should return that image to the `UIViewController` that initiated the camera view flow.

How should I be telling my `UIViewController` flow which `UIViewController` to send the edited image to? Do I need to pass an enum variable along the flow or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think add a complete handler to the UIViewController is a good way. You may send the complete closure to your UIViewController. Enum is good too.